# Check test isolation tool

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, isolation

I have some tests written with mocha.
Probably something wrong with test isolation.
When I start all test it's ok.
When I pick only some `describe` block some test falls.

Did any knows any instruments to check test isolation. Maybe some tools that automatically starts tests/blocks in different order multiple times, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The [rocha](https://github.com/bahmutov/rocha) is an answer.

Finding at mocha GitHub [discussion](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/902)